# How to get list of files that have the most commits in svn repository?

Tags: svn

I have Subversion repository with a lot of files. I would like to know what files where modified a lot in the specific time. Any suggestions how to do it?

Comment: Define "a lot". Many commits? Many changed lines? Many different authors?

Answer (score 1):

First, you can get the list of modified files like this:

```
svn log -r {2010-11-20}:{2011-11-21} -v
```

Then you can count the number of modified files using `sed` or other parsing tools.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a "nice" representation of statistics on your svn repository, check [Statsvn](http://www.statsvn.org/).

> StatSVN retrieves information from a Subversion repository and
>   generates various tables and charts describing the project
>   development, e.g.
>
> ...
>
> - File count Average file size Largest files Files with most revisions
>
> ...

As [shown here](http://www.statsvn.org/statsvn/file_sizes.html) (scroll down to the end), you can have the top modified files in your repository.